# How do we call a function that map different variables to different values?

Tags: functions

Let's say we have a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and $\forall x \in X$ and $\forall y \in X$, $x \ne y \implies f(x) \ne f(y)$.

Is there a specific name for this kind of function, which has the property of "different input has different output"? Thanks.

Comment: The word is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

Comment: There are injective, surjective and bijective functions.

Comment: thanks for answers guys.